# Compute forecasts and 90% forecast intervals for ARIMA(p,1,q) models

Tags: forecasting, arima, prediction-interval

Consider the two models (ARIMA(1,1,0) and (ARIMA(0,1,1)):
[image]

Comment: Note: these are forecast intervals or prediction intervals, not confidence intervals. The former two (which are roughly synonymic) deal with forecasting an outcome of a random variable while the latter one deals with estimating a value of a parameter.

Comment: My apologies, it should say forecast intervals in the heading.

Comment: You may edit the heading, I think it is a good idea to do so.

Answer (score 2):

For the ARIMA(0,1,1) model in part (b), since you only know $r_{49}$ and $r_{50}$ you need to do finite history forecasting, that is, you want the expectation and variance of $r_{51},\dots, r_{54}$ conditional on $r_{49}$ and $r_{50}$ only.  This differs form the infinite history forecast which depends on all the past for models with a moving average part.  The most efficient way is to compute this is usually via Kalman filtering and forecasting. Using functions for this in the `stats` R-package, we find

```
# construct state space representation
mod <- makeARIMA(theta=-.43, phi=0, Delta = 1)
# run the kalman filter given the two observations
mod <- KalmanRun(c(33.4, 33.9), mod, update=TRUE)
# put final state estimate into new model object
mod <- attr(mod,"mod")
# compute forecasts via the Kalman filter
> KalmanForecast(4,mod)
$pred
[1] 33.71854 33.71854 33.71854 33.71854

$var
[1] 1.028853 1.353753 1.678653 2.003553
```

From this you can easily get 90% forecast limits.  Note that the 1-step ahead forecast variance is larger than the white noise variance $\sigma_a^2=1$ (it would be equal to $\sigma_a^2$ only for an infinite history forecast).

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to do this for each $l$ because the idea is the same.

What you have here are ARIMA(1,1,0) and ARIMA(0,1,1) models. Thus, let

$X_t = (1-B)r_t = r_t - r_{t-1}$. Then,

$(1-0.43B)X_t = a_t$ is an $AR(1)$. Rewrite this as,

$X_t = 0.43 X_{t-1} + a_t $

Let's now find $r_{50}(1) = E[\ r_{51} |\ r_{50}, r_{49}, ...] $

Since from the first equation $ X_t =   r_t - r_{t-1}$ we know that $ X_{51} = r_{51} - r_{50}  \rightarrow r_{51} = X_{51} + r_{50}.$

Thus, $r_{50}(1) = E[\ X_{51} + r_{50} \ | \ r_{50}, r_{49}, ...]$. Note that if we know the values of $r_{50}, r_{49}, ...$ we also know the values of $X_{50}, X_{49}, ...$

Therefore, $r_{50}(1) = E [ 0.43 X_{50} + a_{51} + r_{50}\ |  \ r_{50}, r_{49},...] = 0.43X_{50} + 0 + r_{50} = 0.43(r_{50} - r_{49}) + r_{50} = 0.43(33.9-33.4) + 33.9 =  0.215 + 33.9 = 34.115.$

We can continue this recursion over and over again to get the lags that you need. The idea is that we keep backing out until we get to a point where all of the values in the expectation are known given the observed values. For example,

$r_{50}(2) = E[ \ r_{52} | \ r_{50}, r_{49}...] = E[X_{52} + r_{51} | \ r_{50}, r_{49}...] = E[X_{52} + X_{51} + r_{50} | \ r_{50}, r_{49}...]  \\=E[0.43X_{51} + a_{52} + 0.43X_{50} + a_{51} + r_{50} |\ r_{50}, r_{49}...] = E[0.43(0.43X_{50} + a_{51}) + a_{52} + 0.43X_{50} + a_{51} + r_{50} |\ r_{50}, r_{49}...].$

For the prediction intervals, we will need the prediction error. If $e_{50}(1) = r_{51} - r_{50}(1)$, (ie. the difference between the actual value and the forecasted value we just derived) then

$e_{50}(1) = X_{51} + r_{50} -  (0.43X_{50} + r_{50}) = 0.43X_{50} + a_{51} + r_{50} - 0.43X_{50} - r_{50} = a_{51}. $

A 90% prediction interval is:

$[r_{50}(1) - 1.64 \sqrt{Var[e_{50}(1)]},\ r_{50}(1) + 1.64 \sqrt{Var[e_{50}(1)]}]$

Since $Var[e_{50}(1)] = Var[a_{51}] = 1$ then the prediction interval is just $[34.115 - 1.64(1), 34.115 + 1.64(1)] =[32.475, 35.775] $

For $e_{50}(2)$ this will end up being $0.43a_{51} + a_{52} + a_{51}$ which are just the error terms that become zero in the expectation when we derive the forecast. Regardless, $Var[e_{50}(2)] = Var[1.43a_{51} + a_{52}] = 1.43^2(1) + (1) = 3.0449 $ (independence of $a_t$ being used here). Plug into the formula again for the confidence interval (using $r_{50}(2)$ of course) and repeat.

We can repeat this for the other forecasting periods and for part b) using the exact same substitution where in that case you will have $X_t = a_t - 0.43a_{t-1}$, a $MA(1)$. Note that the calculations quickly become tedious and so I recommend trying to spot a pattern after doing the first couple lags to find a general form for both the forecasts and prediction errors.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I must add; I had a slight issue when I did part b). The problem resides in conditioning on $r_{50}, r_{49},...$ implying that we know the values of $a_{50}, a_{49},...$ but to my belief the question does not provide enough information to get these values. For example, to me the one step ahead forecast is simply $-0.43a_{50} + r_{50} $ but to get $r_{50}$ we use $0.5 = a_{50} - 0.43a_{49}$. This however requires $a_{49}$ and that needs $a_{48}$, etc. Unless the question does not necessarily want a numeric answer I am unsure if this is possible, though I could be mistaken.